# JS for loop resetting to 0 between loops for no reason

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following for loop in my Javascript:

```
  for (x=0;x<newPlayer.length;x++){
    console.log(newPlayer.length,x);
    console.log("bigloopstart");
    $(".timeline-grid").append(
      "<div class='timeline-straight timeline-dashed timeline-half-left' style='grid-column-start:" + newPlayer[x].c + "; grid-row-start:" + newPlayer[x].r + `'>
        <div class='timeline-icon ` + eventDate + "'>" + iconhtml + `</div>
        <div class='timeline-team'><span>` + eventOldTeam[x] + `</span></div>
      </div>`
    );
    console.log(newPlayer.length,x);
    for (i=0,t=activeplayers.length;i<t;i++){
      if (newPlayer[x].name == activeplayers[i].name){
        activeplayers.splice(i,1);
        console.log("smallloop");
        break;
      }
    }
    console.log(newPlayer.length,x);
    console.log("bigloopend");
  }
```

In the case I'm testing it with, `newPlayer` has length 2. The loop runs through twice, but then runs a third time, spitting out an error because it can't read the properties of the nonexistent third object in the array.

It seems that for some reason `x` is resetting to 0 after the second loop:

[image]

I even tried putting the x++ inside the loop:

```
  for (x=0;x<newPlayer.length;){
    console.log(newPlayer.length,x);
    console.log("bigloopstart");
    $(".timeline-grid").append(
      "<div class='timeline-straight timeline-dashed timeline-half-left' style='grid-column-start:" + newPlayer[x].c + "; grid-row-start:" + newPlayer[x].r + `'>
        <div class='timeline-icon ` + eventDate + "'>" + iconhtml + `</div>
        <div class='timeline-team'><span>` + eventOldTeam[x] + `</span></div>
      </div>`
    );
    console.log(newPlayer.length,x);
    for (i=0,t=activeplayers.length;i<t;i++){
      if (newPlayer[x].name == activeplayers[i].name){
        activeplayers.splice(i,1);
        console.log("smallloop");
        break;
      }
    }
    x++;
    console.log(newPlayer.length,x);
    console.log("bigloopend");
  }
```

but then the console looks like this:

[image]

It seems that between the second and third loops `x` is being reset to 0 and I have no idea why. Any pointers?

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: There seem to be syntax errors in the string after `$(".timeline-grid").append(...` relating to quotes and newlines: you can't insert random newlines in strings and quotes must be balanced. Also take care with the backtick character `\``, it's not a quote character.

Comment: @RobG it looks like a bit of a mess, but it's actually closed properly; I used the backtick to enclose multiple lines of HTML. Regardless - even when I replaced it with `$(".timeline-grid").append("test");, it still reset `x` to 0, causing the same error.

Comment: From the code shown I can't see any reason why the loop would restart, but also given that it did seem to restart with (according to the console) `newPlayer.length` still 2 and `x` now 0, the undefined error doesn't make sense because it's not trying to read a third non-existing element in the array, it's back to trying to read `newPlayer[0].c`.

Comment: @RobG - But... the backtick *is* a quote character now, for string template literals - which allow newlines. wwsalmon - given you're using the backtick, you could tidy up your code by using the `${}` syntax rather than concatenating separate literals and variables, e.g., `\`<span>${eventOldTeam[x]}</span>\``.

Comment: @nnnnnn—ok, but the mix is a little difficult to read. Agree that the OP should use a template or standard string concatenation, not a blend. PS: I can't see the images, only the code.

Comment: Use `var` to define your variables in for loops in case javascript gets confused